# Coherence Extend Proxy putting uninitialized objects in cache

Tags: oracle-coherence

We have an existing app that uses an Oracle Coherence cluster to put/get POFable objects to/from a cluster cache. I'm trying to modify it to use an extend proxy to do the same thing. So far I've been able to startup a separate proxy process that connects to our cluster, and I have modified the cache config for the existing app to connect to the extend proxy. At startup, everything looks happy and connected. But when I try to put something into the cache, the objects end up with all their fields uninitialized.

I haven't changed any client application code when it comes to putting key/value pairs into the cache, because as I understand it, using extend is supposed to be transparent to clients. Here's the code that puts objects into cache:

```
// Initiliaze POF object from DB; MyObject implements EvolvablePortableObject
MyObject o = new MyObject();
o.setField1(...);
o.setField2(...);
o.setField3(...);

CacheFactory.getCache("cache-name").put(key, o, expireTime);
```

The net result is that the object ends up in the cache with all of its fields uninitialized (i.e. all zeroes and nulls). I have used the debugger to confirm that inside the client, the object is fully initialized and all of its fields are populated as I expect. Likewise, I have used a debugger to show that the object is uninitialized when MyObject.writeExternal() is called inside the proxy app. So something is breaking down between the client and proxy but I'm not sure what. Both point to the same POF config file and have the same classpath, so they should be seeing the same POF schemes and Java objects. I have turned logging up to level 9 on both client and proxy but I don't see any messages that are out of the ordinary. When I run without the proxy, the client is able to put the same objects into the cache without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this issue, the root cause ended up being some missing  tags. I already had it defined under the acceptor-config for the extend service:

```
        <serializer>
           <class-name>com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext</class-name>
           <init-params>
              <init-param>
                 <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type>
                 <param-value>pof-config.xml</param-value>
              </init-param>
           </init-params>
        </serializer>
```

(same thing needed for Invocation Service if you define one).

But also had to add a similar config to the client config to make things match:

```
<defaults>
  <serializer>
     <class-name>com.tangosol.io.pof.ConfigurablePofContext</class-name>
     <init-params>
        <init-param>
           <param-type>java.lang.String</param-type>
           <param-value>pof-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
     </init-params>
  </serializer>
```